# Pass addition information in Connection String

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I want to pass an additonal string value in connection string so that can see which person was connected.

This connection string is login as sql authentication and log file will show sql user id and computer name but i want to add user name who is connected to my applicaiton.

Is there a way to pass user information who is using that application and add in sql server log file. e.g. message.

```
string constr = "WorkStation id=computerName;"
                    + "packet size=0000"
                    + ";user id=user001;"
                    + "data source=servername;"
                    + "persist security info=True;"
                    + "initial catalog=database"
                    + ";password=password";
```

Answer (score 1):

A connection string is intended as a single string that is used by all the users. It's also something that usually is shared by multiple users, because a database has a limited amount of open connections possible. If you have a connection open for every user, you're going to run into scaling issues and connection pool overflows.

If you want to know what user issued the command, the best solution is to use a stored procedure that takes the user information as a parameter and logs it through that.

However, passing user info through the logic layer to the data layer is a code smell. If you need to know who did a transaction, it's better that you log this in the application code instead of through the SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

There is simply no way of doing that directly in to the SQL Logs.

If you want to log the usage you have 2 good options:

1) Create a different SQL user for each username in your application. This is probably only possible if you have Active Directory integration, otherwise it could be a very tedious proces of adding new SQL users

2) Log your application usage from the application into a seperate SQL table. This is how a lot of applications works, and would be considered best practice in this case.